# query on the first n rows from large table without checking all rows -oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Every query is taking a lot of time on my table which is very large. For testing purpose I want queries to be implemented for first few rows of the table. for ex : In  select * from table where ROWNUM=1,there would be a check for all rows i.e if ROWNUM is 1 or not. But I want to test my queries for few rows only to save time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select only top n rown then you must use -

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ROWNUM <= N;
```

Comment: I think is `WHERE ROWNUM <= N;`, otherwise is (N-1) rows.

Comment: My doubt is while implementation of this query,will all rows of the table be checked i.e if thir ROWNUM is less than N or not? If that is the case,then it would still take lot of time for large table

Comment: Maybe oracle already have an optimization for that. Just try it. Also you can create an aditional column update with ROWNUM and create an index for that column

Comment: No, all the rows will not check. ORACLE assign a dummy value to each row and will start fetching rows, as it reaches to =N, immediately stops and shows the o/p.

Answer (score 0):

rownum is a pseudocolumn it does not exist on the table records and is assigned at runtime once the predicate (where clause) phase of the query is completed. Due to this only the first query returns the result

```
select * from hr.employees where employee_id >190 and rownum<2;-- Will return one row
select * from hr.employees where employee_id >190 and rownum>2;-- Won't return any resultset
select * from hr.employees where employee_id >190 and rownum=3;-- Won't return any resultset
```

Reason behind the last two queries for not returning the resultset is once the predicate (employee_id >190) gets completed and a rownum is assigned to the first row then for (2 query rownum>2) 1>2 returns false and for (3 query rownum=3) 1=3 returns false so no data is returned.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a mini test-table for your testing queries?

```
create table my_test_table as select * from big_table where rownum <= n;
```

Now you could run something like

```
select count(*) from my_test_table where color='red';
```

and divide that result by `n` to get your estimate for what fraction of the rows have `color='red'` in your big database.  Of course, note that you could get really unlucky (i.e. your small table could be a poor sample of the total table population), in which case you can probably just increase `n` to achieve a better sample.

If you can't or would rather not create a new table, you can certainly just use a nested query:

```
select * from (select * from big_table where rownum <= n)
  where <condition>;
```